# Log all the data accessed by an app

Tags: android

is it possible to retrieve all the data that the app has accessed in your phone and print it out? For instance the app retrieve my imei, my location and I would like to print it out to a log, like imei:123456789, location: 40° N, 74° W.
I know that in xprivacy it is possible to manually check what have been accessed and restrict the access to some information. But I'd like to know if there's an app or an alternative already to export the data in that matter.

Thanks and happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  Technically, there are a couple of ways you might get quite a lot of the information, but they aren't very practical.

For example, if you had sufficient privileges, you could monitor your app with strace.  This would catch kernel calls.  The kinds of data access you're talking about would all involve system calls.  Or you could straight up debug an app and gather information that way (not at all practical).

Making that information available constantly would kill performance, so it's not something you can get at normally.